# SQL Server query: Adjust money column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to do the following WITHOUT CURSORS. Is it possible?

I have this variable:

```
DECLARE @Amount MONEY = 800;
```

Sample table that I current have:

```
EntryID    Amount
--------------------------------------------
1       200
2       250
3       600
4       100
...     ....(could be many more rows)
```

I want to be able to update the table to only show the "Amount" that it needs to add up to the @Amount variable ($800). So I'd like the table to end up like this:

```
EntryID    Amount
--------------------------------------------
1       200 (uses up full 200)
2       250 (uses up full 250)
3       350 (uses up 350 of the 600)
```

OR LIKE THIS

```
EntryID    Amount     Distrib
--------------------------------------------
1       200        200
2       250        250
3       600        350
4       100        0
...     ...            ...
```

So the `SUM()` is equal to `@Amount`

Thanks in advance!

PS - I'm doing this in SQL Server 2012

**UPDATE:**

Here's my final solution.  Thanks again, Gordon:

```
DECLARE @Amount money = 800;
DECLARE @tmpPaymentDist TABLE (EntryID INT, Amount MONEY, Distrib MONEY);

INSERT INTO @tmpPaymentDist (EntryID, Amount) VALUES (1, 200);
INSERT INTO @tmpPaymentDist (EntryID, Amount) VALUES (2, 250);
INSERT INTO @tmpPaymentDist (EntryID, Amount) VALUES (3, 600);
INSERT INTO @tmpPaymentDist (EntryID, Amount) VALUES (4, 100);

with toupdate as (
    select t.*,
        (case when sum(amount) over (order by entryid) <= @amount
        then amount
        when sum(amount) over (order by entryid) < @amount + amount
        then @amount - (sum(amount) over (order by entryid) - amount)
        else 0
    end) as new_distrib
    from @tmpPaymentDist t
)

update T set distrib = new_distrib 
FROM @tmpPaymentDist T
INNER JOIN toupdate T2 ON T2.EntryID = T.EntryID
WHERE T2.new_distrib > 0

SELECT * FROM @tmpPaymentDist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this without cursors, using cumulative sums:

```
select t.*,
       (case when sum(amount) over (order by entryid) <= @amount
             then amount
             when sum(amount) over (order by entryid) < @amount + amount
             then @amount - (sum(amount) over (order by entryid) - amount)
             else 0
        end) as distrib
from table t;
```

That is, use cumulative sums for the calculation.

For an `update`, you can use the same logic:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             (case when sum(amount) over (order by entryid) <= @amount
                   then amount
                   when sum(amount) over (order by entryid) < @amount + amount
                   then @amount - (sum(amount) over (order by entryid) - amount)
                   else 0
              end) as new_distrib
      from table t
     )
update toudpate
    set distrib = new_distrib;
```

Comment: IT WORKS! I knew it was going to be something crazy like that! LOL  Thanks for the help Gordon